# Modify rails new command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When executing the `rails new ...` command, eventually the task `bundle install` will be executed. For many of my projects I require the same gems and have to add them manually *after* creating the app and then run `bundle install` again manually.

Is there any way to modify the `rails new` command to write those gems inside the Gemfile *while* generating the app, so that when it executes bundle install all my gems are already in place? Ideally only triggered if I give an optional parameter?

Comment: FYI: You can do `rails new app --skip-bundle`, and it won't run `bundle install` directly. You can then add the gems, and run bundle yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mind it running bundle - in fact, I want to use it to directly install the gems I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates)